# Firefox renders html page with .html extension while chrome diaplays plain text

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

Request: https://otherdomain.com/page

Response from the page:

```
Content-Length: 148
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:22:53 GMT
Server: Server

text""<html><script>console.log('hi')</script></html>
```

As we can see that there is no content-type header specified.

If we Put .HTML to url as below:

https://otherdomain.com/page.html

In firefox the page will be rendered as html page while in chrome it displays plain text.

How can i force the chrome browser to render this page as html?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your page??

Comment: @Reddy Question Updated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have access to the server to set mime types? If not you can add a single PHP line at the top of your page that can set the MIME header:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html'); ?>
```

That's assuming you have PHP enabled on on the server. The line needs to be before all the other content at the top of the code, i.e. above the first `<html>` tag.

Comment: I dont have access to the server. But I have manipulated firefox to render it as html page by simply putting .html to url. I am expecting similar force technique for chrome

Comment: Since i dont have access to server, I am looking for manipulating in browser

Comment: what about with an extension on chrome such as: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka?hl=en-US

Comment: Extensions are not the case. I am looking for similar technique for chrome browser that worked in firefox.